# Wildfly 18 - drools 7.39.0-Final: Deploy app and get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Tags: wildfly, drools, kie

Been trying to migrate an application up to WF 18.0 and drools 7.39.0-Final.
Drools 7.39.0-Final is the last WF18 release.

One of our applications uses drools/kie.

I get errors like the following when trying to deploy it.

> "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"policy-ear.ear\".\"policy-beans.jar\".component.CepRuleEngineHolder.START"
> => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
> Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier$LazyHolder"

From searching around I found that this can be caused by static stuff/constructors failing.
So I downloaded the source and as an experiment changed things as below.  This fixes it.
This example below shows what I did for the KieServices class.

Note that the error above is for a DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier class, I tried to apply my change to that class, but it's a huge build and had some other issues.  Before I chased that I wanted to ask if there's a better way to do this?  It doesn't seem like I should have to do this at all, this is the latest published drools for WF18.

For KieServices, I changed this:

```
/**
 * A Factory for this KieServices
 */
class Factory {

    static class LazyHolder {
        private static KieServices INSTANCE = ServiceRegistry.getInstance().get(KieServices.class);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the KieServices singleton
     */
    public static KieServices get() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

to:

```
/**
 * A Factory for this KieServices
 */
class Factory {
    static private KieServices instance = null;
    public static class LazyHolder {
        public LazyHolder() {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the KieServices singleton
     */
    public static KieServices get() {
        if ( instance == null) {
        instance =  ServiceRegistry.getInstance().get(KieServices.class);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I wonder if I did something wrong with the installation or with configuration, It doesn't seem like I should have had to make these modifications, and am looking for a better, recommended solution to the original error.